# UIActionsheet location changes from landscape to portrait mode

Tags: objective-c, uiactionsheet

I have a tableview where long press on a row triggers actionsheet - options. The action sheet is displayed properly in landscape/portrait mode when I press anywhere on the row (think iPad screen). But when I long press on the extreme right hand side of the row in landscape mode (near disclosure indicator), and change to the portrait mode, The actionsheet gets displayed as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `UIActionSheet` doesn't anchor itself to anything, so when the screen rotates it stays where it is, while everything else has moved. You want to redisplay the action sheet in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:` or `didAnimateRotationFromInterfaceOrientation`.

Comment: Tried this but doesnt work :|                                         - (void) didAnimateRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer                         {
    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        CGPoint point = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
        self.contactIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
        if (self.contactIndexPath != nil) {
            [self showPopoverForContactAtPoint:point];
        }
    }
}

Comment: Somehow cant format the comment here: Please visit the link for the code:  https://gist.github.com/akiitrivedi/5339115 Thanks

Comment: Those aren't the correct method definitions. They do not have a gesture recognizer as a parameter. Check the [UIViewController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Ok.Since I am new to this I dont know how to display             [self showPopoverForContactAtPoint:point]; without using the "point".

Comment: You'll need to keep track of that, but at the same time, that point will also be in a different spot on the screen. So you want to keep track of the actual view that was touched, and then recalculate the point after rotation.

Comment: Ok. That seems quite complicated than I originally thought.Thanks again.